# Make notepad++ default editor for all Notepad documents

Tags: notepad++

I am wanting to make notepad++ my default editor for all files that would open using Notepad. Is there a quick way to do this?

I know I can choose the default app for specific files types but to go through all of them but that is very long winded. Is there a way to change the default application to Notepad++ for all file types that are supposed to open with Notepad.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no magic buttons for everything.

You can use DISM to export default associations to .xml file, open it, see which extensions get opened by notepad, and change the appropriate values to notepad++ instead of notepad (AppIDs). Then you can import the new xml file.

See [this microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/export-or-import-default-application-associations) for more info.